# Custom views filter + Add a groupBy in the query() function

Tags: views

On a domain site (domain access module), I want to filter medias/nodes by the related domains to the current user. For this I have created a custom views filter : I analyse the user domains and modify the query to display only the needed nodes/medias. Here is the code of my custom views filter:

```
  /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function query() {
  $this->ensureMyTable();
  // Load the current user.
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
  $domains = array();
  // Retrieve the domains of the current user.
  $user_domains = $user->get('field_domain_access')->getValue();
  foreach ($user_domains as $domain) {
    $domains[] = $domain['target_id'];
  }
  if (!empty($this->value) and $user->get('field_domain_all_affiliates')->value == 0) {
    // Add an additional condition to filter contents/medias by the user domains.
    $this->query->addWhere($this->options['group'], 'node__field_domain_access.field_domain_access_target_id', $domains, 'IN');  
  }
}
```

But, I get duplicates results in my views.
If I use this filter, I need to desactivate the SQL rewriting option, so I can't use the distinct option to remove duplicates.

Is there a solution to add a groupBy to remove duplicates? I tried to use this code without sucess:

```
$this->query->groupBy('nid');
$this->query->distinct(); // don't work
```

Do I add a new field in my query (node field) ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use [Sql::addOrderBy](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!src!Plugin!views!query!Sql.php/function/Sql%3A%3AaddOrderBy/8.2.x)

Comment: Try with `$this->ensureMyTable()->query->addOrderBy('node', 'nid', $order = 'ASC', $alias = '', []);`

Comment: You can use hook_query_alter(), see [this](https://www.zyxware.com/articles/4289/solved-drupal-7-views-how-to-remove-duplicates-programmatically) web page

Comment: Thanks Berramou ! If I add this code, duplicates aren't visible : $this->query->addOrderBy('node', 'nid', $order = 'ASC', $alias = '', []); $this->query->options['distinct'] = TRUE; But, on my views table, I can't sort the results with any sort filters. Do I add another sort filters in my custom filter?